# What does Invisibility actually mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some of the Demon Hunter's powers (specifically Smoke Screen) cause invisibility.
What does this actually accomplish? It seems like enemies keep coming at me and attacking, but usually when I use it I'm in the thick of things and not paying more attention to not dying than whether or not my health is stable for those 2 seconds. My roommate thought it might grant invulnerability for those few seconds, but I can't find anything to back that up.

Comment: don't have a DH, so can't answer from experiance, but if its anything like the invisibility the monsters get, it makes you immune to everything until it wears off (can't target, can't hit with aoe's - nothing)

Answer (score 4):

Smoke Screen does in fact give invulnerability. It's especially handy to avoid dying. This is why it was patched a few days ago to be reduced to a duration of 1.5 seconds instead of 2 seconds.

It's not complete invulnerability mind you. Some damage, whether by design or bug, can still get through. One example is molten tiles, which can cause a strange health bubble rubberband effect and leave you at 1 hp.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a temporary limited invincibility, it will also drop threat temporarily onto other party members/your follower. For example, using smoke screen on pull at Belial will result in the four adds that are present at the start from agroing your party or follower.

Comment: There is no threat or aggro mechanic in Diablo 3.

Comment: Not in the way you'd think of it in terms of World of Warcraft, but without a threat or agro mechanic, the adds on Belial wouldn't go for your follower with smokescreen up on pull, only to immediately have half of them switch target (the ones closest to you) when Smokescreen drops off. Test it yourself :-)